# Calculate difference between first non-zero value and last non-zero value through multiple instances in Pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a DataFrame with column col_c values of 0, positive integers, 0, negative integers, 0. I want to return a new column (col_d as shown below) with values calculating the difference between the first non-zero value and last non-zero value. The original DataFrame demonstrates col_c values:

```
   col_a col_b col_c
 1  AB    0     0     
 2  AB    0     0     
 3  AB    1     1     
 4  AB    1     2     
 5  AB    1     5     
 6  AB    1     3     
 7  AB    0     0     
 8  AB    0     0     
 9  AB   -1    -1     
10  AB   -1    -2     
11  AB   -1    -5     
12  AB   -1    -3     
13  AB    0     0
14  AB    0     0
```

I want to return a DataFrame as follows, where the values 2 in rows 6 and 12 are calculated from col_c as (3-1) = 2 and (-3 - -1) = -2:

```
   col_a col_b col_c col_d
 1  AB    0     0      0
 2  AB    0     0      0
 3  AB    1     1      0
 4  AB    1     2      0
 5  AB    1     5      0
 6  AB    1     3      2
 7  AB    0     0      0
 8  AB    0     0      0
 9  AB   -1    -1      0
10  AB   -1    -2      0
11  AB   -1    -5      0
12  AB   -1    -3      2
13  AB    0     0      0
14  AB    0     0      0
```

Comment: BTW, `-3 - (-1) == -2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**High Level**

- Find the zeros: `df.col_c.eq(0)`
- Use `cumsum` to create groups
- Replace the actual zero positions with `-1` because it's the non-zeros I care about
- Perform a `groupby` with `agg`

  - `'last'` to get last in group
  - `'first'` to get first in group
  - `'last_valid_index` to figure out where to put it
  - Drop the `-1` group because those were the zeros I don't care about
- Create a dictionary with the keys as the results from `last_valid_index` and values are the differences between `'last'` and `'first'`
- Create new column with `assign` and `index.map`

  - `index.map` requires a callable, so I use the `dict.get` method.  However, we want to default to zero so it's convenient to that `dict.get` can take a default value.

---

```
m = df.col_c.eq(0)
g = m.cumsum().mask(m, -1)

d = df.col_c.groupby(g).agg(['last', 'first', lambda x: x.last_valid_index()]).drop(-1)
k = dict(zip(d['<lambda>'], d['last'] - d['first']))

df.assign(col_d=df.index.map(lambda x: k.get(x, 0)))

   col_a  col_b  col_c  col_d
1     AB      0      0      0
2     AB      0      0      0
3     AB      1      1      0
4     AB      1      2      0
5     AB      1      5      0
6     AB      1      3      2
7     AB      0      0      0
8     AB      0      0      0
9     AB     -1     -1      0
10    AB     -1     -2      0
11    AB     -1     -5      0
12    AB     -1     -3     -2
13    AB      0      0      0
14    AB      0      0      0
```

Comment: Deleted previous thank you comment - thanks again! One more addition to this problem:

Is there a single series solution to this case? This works as implemented for a series (that is, multiple values in col_c). For just a single value in col_c (suppose a Series segment of 0, 5, 0 instead of the previous 0, 1, 5, 0), is there a way to return that single value as well?

Let me know if I may phrase this question better - my apologies as I am still relatively new to posting. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way that uses looping:

```
df['col_d'] = 0
count = 0
for row in range(0, len(df)-1):
    if df['col_c'][count] != 0 and df['col_c'][count+1] == 0:
        df['col_d'][count] = df['col_c'][count] - df['col_b'][count]
    count += 1
```

First, create column d and set it to 0 for all rows. Then, loop through the dataframe and look for rows where:

- column c does not equal 0
- in the row below, column c does equal 0

Then set column d in that row to: column c minus column b.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you are calculating the absoluate difference between the last two columns, no matter the values are 0 or non-zero. If this is the case, you can do this:

```
df['new'] = df.iloc[:,[-2,-1]].apply(lambda (x,y):abs(x-y), axis=1)
```

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect and if you fixed it to `df.iloc[:,[-2,-1]].apply(lambda t:abs(t[0] - t[1]), axis=1)` it produces incorrect results.  Also, it depends on `col_b` always having the appropriate value which OP never said was the case.